# How do I capture the value of a text box and use it as a variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, visual-studio-2012

Let me preface this by saying I am very new to C# and I am converting a program from VB.net to C#.

I'm working in `Visual Studio 2012` and running a `SQL Server 2008R2`

OK, So I have a form, Form1. on this form is a Text box a user can fill out, TextBox1.  Now I want to use the information in the text box as a variable to pull information from a database and populate a text box (textbox2) on a different form (form2) this is the code I am currently using on form 2

```
    private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Name = Form1.TextBox1.Text;
        this.TBMainTableAdapter.FillBy(Name);

    }
```

I've also tried loading it like this:

```
this.TBMainTableAdapter.FillBy(Form1.TextBox1.Text);
```

these both give me the  "Object reference is required for a non-static field... error

In VB.Net it was a lot easier, I coded it like this, and it worked perfectly.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Me.TBMainTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.ProjectDataset.TBName, TextBoxName.Text)
End Sub
```

Is there something I am missing in the code behind? I tried changing the code on the text box

from

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextBox1;
```

to

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextBox1;
```

While this cleared up the errors on pulling the variable, it threw a bunch more errors in the code-behind on form 1, the "cant be accessed with an instance, give it a nametype" error

Would it be worth it to change all the errors on the code behind. and more importantly is that the right way to do this?

---

OK so I added these 2 under

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
Form1  form1;
public Form2(Form1 frm)

    {    
        form1 = frm;
    }

    Form2 frm = new Form1(this);
```

Im getting the "Method must have a return type error" at the "Public Form2(Form1 frm)" line
and
"error Namespace.Form1 does not have a constructor that takes 1 arguments" at the Form2 frm = new Form1(this); line

also if I put the getter property in Form1, I get an error about declaring 2 objects with the same name.  Cant find anywhere that declares TextBox1 except in the code behind where its declared at the very end of the code behind as

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TxtBox1
```

and if I put the getter below that, I get an only assignment, call, etc can be used as a statement error

Comment: you don't want to make your `TextBox` static. even stronger, don't change your code behind if you don't know what you are doing. it's auto generated and your changes might be lost in the long run

Comment: Your code doesn't show the declaration of Form1, but I assume Form1 is the class name of your form (like "public partial class Form1 : Form").  If so, then Form1.TextBox1 won't work.  You can't use the class name to try to access a member of an instance of the class.

Comment: MuhammadHani, that wont work because TextBox1 is on a different form than the one i am calling it from.

Comment: Mbeckish. your exactly right, that is how its declared. so then how would you call on it from another form?

Comment: @JoeK - See Nikola Davidovic's answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to return a value from main form to a differnt form or class(C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391795/how-to-return-a-value-from-main-form-to-a-differnt-form-or-classc)

Comment: @mbeckish I see how the concept is the same, passing a value from one form to another, but I cant figure out how to translate that from the value that is returned in the function "count" to what is entered in my textbox.  Ive been able to call a method from another form, insert a variable and return a result from a function, but for the life of me, I cant get it to read what is entered in the textbox

Comment: Did you follow @NikolaDavidovic's suggestion and make sure you are using a reference to the original form, and not just instantiating a new copy of the form?

Comment: tried to. added the info i put into my form and the errors I am getting above...

Comment: The code you said you added to the Form1 should be added to the Form2 instead. Follow carefully what I told you to do and where to insert the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the Form1 in your Form2 object in order to use the content of the control from the Form1. Moreover, your textBox1 should be declared public or you should create the getter property for it. You can use a lot of things but if Form1 is needed in the the Form2, then the simplest thing you could do is to pass the reference of the Form1 through the constructor of the Form2.

```
Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 frm)
{
    form1 = frm;
}
```

Add the getter property for the textBox1 in the Form1:

```
public TextBox TextBox1
{
    get
    {
       this.textBox1;
    }
}
```

You can call this constructor from the Form1 method like this:

```
From2 frm = new Form2(this);
```

and then you could call:

```
private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string Name = form1.TextBox1.Text;
    this.TBMainTableAdapter.FillBy(Name);

}
```

Comment: If I do that, will it TextBox1 still have the info entered into it in the existing form1?

Comment: Check the code now, notice the form1.TextBox1.Text line, this is for accessing the textBox1 through the property TextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm missing something, but the method `FillBy` takes two parameters, first is the `DataTable` to fill and the second the `Name`, so change it to:

```
this.TBMainTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.ProjectDataset.TBName, Name);
```

The method with one parameter is `TBMainTableAdapter.Fill(DataTable table)`.

Edit: overlooked that you are on Form2 but the `TextBox` is on Form1 as Nikola has pointed out, that's of course an important fact. I  Keep this answer  since it might be helpful anyway.