# Set Value to object from another Form

Tags: c#

I'm working on a WindowsFormProject in C# of which carry the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
    }
}
}
```

this is code for Form1;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.textBox1.Text = "prova";

        f1.Refresh();

    }
}
}
```

end this is code for Form2.

the goal is to write a text in the textbox of the form 1, I set the access modifier as public, but does not work

Any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to return a value from main form to a differnt form or class(C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391795/how-to-return-a-value-from-main-form-to-a-differnt-form-or-classc)

Comment: @krillgar in my opinion is not the same question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In Form2:

```
public Form _parent;

public Form2(Form Parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._parent = Parent;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._parent.textBox1.Text = "prova";

    }
```

In Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(this);
        f.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I have this error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1' and no extension method 'textBox1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\cristian\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form2.cs 24 26 WindowsFormsApplication2

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the "button1_Click" in Form2 you are creating a new instance of "Form1" so Form2 does'nt really "knows" the Form1 that is allready open,

You should pass this object reference (Form1) to Form2,
Similar to the solution of Marcio but instead of passong the inherite class "Form" you should pass "Form1"

In Form2:

```
public Form1 _parent;

public Form2(Form1 parent) //<-- parent is the reference for the first form ("Form1" object)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._parent = parent;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._parent.textBox1.Text = "prova"; // you won't get an exception here because _parant is from type Form1 and not Form

}
```

In Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2(this);   //<- "this" is the reference for the current "Form1" object
    f.Show();
}
```